# Is there a way to use translateY like a negative margin?

Tags: css, transform, translate

This is my example: https://jsfiddle.net/a1xxj4j7/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="text">
  </div>
  <div id="float">
    asljsfjjddf
    fjsfd

    fd
    jff
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
  background: black;
}

#text{
  min-height: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#float{
  background: red;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 0 20%;
}
```

I want the #float div to stay at the bottom of the container #text with a 50% offset of its height. That works, problem is since the #text div is rendered before translating it leaves its remaining original height at the bottom. I would like the #text bottom to equal the bottom the #container div so that is "pushes" just the space in the offset.
Of course this would perfectly work if I applied a negative margin-top to the #text but the content is dynamic so I can't set a fixed height!
Is there a trick in èure CSS or do I need to go with JS?

Thanks

Comment: Have you played with position: absolute ?  That was my first thought

Comment: So you don't want the black space at the bottom?

Comment: Transforms are **purely visual** they do not affect actual layout.

Comment: I confess though I'm unclear on what it is you are trying to achieve. What is this "offset" for?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/IuLfJ?q=difference&limit=mine

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm trying to position the #float div (on top of the #text div (at the bottom part)) at half its height dynamically but having the same result as a negative margin (just like your codepen example #3). I need the #container div to shrink!